# Symfony 4 using Logger and Dump inside a Controller

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm new to Symfony 4, I'm using profiler to debug in a dev environment.

I'm trying to  debug a function in controller/ But I can't use a logger or a dump nothing appear.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as Controller;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ProxyQueryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class CRUDController extends Controller
{
private $logger;

public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

public function batchActionDownload(ProxyQueryInterface $selectedModelQuery)
{

    $this->logger->debug('exampleMethod :: $ourVar at interesting time', [
        'our_var' => $selectedModelQuery
    ]);

    var_dump($selectedModelQuery);
    dump($selectedModelQuery);

    return new RedirectResponse(
        $this->admin->generateUrl('list', $this->admin->getFilterParameters())
    );
}
```

I have no error, but simply my debug isn't showing up.

Any Idea of what I'm doing bad ?

Comment: Is there anything else happening when calling that method? If a redirect is issued, have you checked whether the output is printed when skipping that redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the best way to define the route is to use the annotation. You are new and i don't how know you have defined your route.

But if seems that your functions isn't called. So try to set a route and call it in your browser.

```
/**
 * @Route("/mycrud", name="mycrud")
 */
public function batchActionDownload(ProxyQueryInterface $selectedModelQuery)
```

Then you should be able to open your function in the browser under `http://yourdomain/mycrud`. Then you should see the debug bar and your `var_dump`.

**The next thing is you redirect in your function. So you output something and redirect. You can't see the output in that place. You have to stop the code before output with an `exit` for example.**